# Is this sentence correct:I already have posted the letter

Tags: sentence, syntactic-analysis

"I already have posted the letter."Is this correct

Comment: What do you think? Have you done any research to determine its correctness? What do you suppose could be incorrect about the sentence?

Answer (score 1):

**Already** usually goes with the verb, in ***'mid-position'***.

- she has already graduated”

It can also go at the end of a clause, for ***emphasis***.

- Are you here **already**? You must have run all the way.

The AmE use of a past tense with **already** is becoming common in
BrE.

- I **already told** Jane about the party.

(Oxford Practical English Usage p 296)

Answer (score 0):

While the proposed sentence is not incorrect, it is awkward for most usage.  The more common form in standard American English would be:  "I have already posted the letter."